# How do I console.log my POST. When i try to GET all i get in console is "null"

Tags: javascript, forms, post, get

So here is my code. My `POST` function seems to work. But when I try to `console.log` my POST from the server all I get is "null".

What I need help with is to properly `POST` to my form to the server. And then be able to retrieve it and post it to to my console.

I then have to post it to my website, but that i can manage for myself.

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(this);
  formData.append("store", "vetlekw1");

  fetch("http://folk.ntnu.no/oeivindk/imt1441/storage/add.php?", {
    method: "post",
    body: formData
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
    });
});

document.querySelector(".hent").addEventListener('click', e=>{
    fetch('http://folk.ntnu.no/oeivindk/imt1441/storage/getAll.php?store=vetlekw1')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
    })

})
```

```html
  <section id="addContact">
    <h1>add Contact</h1>
    <form class="form" id="myForm" >
      <label for="fornavn">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fornavn"><br>
      <label for="etternavn">Surname</label>
      <input type="text" id="etternavn"><br/>
      <label for="tlf">Tlf</label>
      <input type="text" id="tlf"><br>
      <button type="submit">add</button>
    </form>
  </section>
<br>

<button class="hent">Get</button>
```

Comment: Have you checked the network tab for more request details?

Comment: Hello! yes. Here is when i post: https://imgur.com/a/sq09CjT

And here is when i try to get it from server: https://imgur.com/a/I8o1jOd

Comment: Issue seems to be on the server side. Can you show `getAll.php` code?

Comment: Also, can you confirm whether data gets added to the database or not?

Comment: currently i dont have a getAll.php code. or i dont have access to it.

This: https://imgur.com/a/sq09CjT is the response i get from server. So something gets added.

Comment: Then it's impossible to say anything. However, can you confirm if any data is actually passed to the API call in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give back the expected data from your server endpoint. Maybe your db query gives no result or you are using a wrong variable or something else.